# Instagram alternative for iPad

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, photos

I'm looking for an iOS app that will offer features similar to that of **[Instagram](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8)**. This app should be *designed specifically for the iPad*.

Feature I'd like to have are:

- apply **filters** to photos
- take photos within the app itself
- export photos to social networks or camera roll

Can you recommend such apps which have been made specifically for the iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself was looking for a good alternative too and I ended up using [Pixlr-o-matic](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixlr-o-matic/id450263811?mt=8). It's a fast and solid app which will allow you to take some pictures, share it with your friends and apply a lot of effect on the photos. You don't even need a phone with a camera to make this kind of pictures :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Process is my darling at the moment for iPad capture, edit, post and is most similar to the workflow for creating content comparable to Instagram.  It lacks the hosting and discovery aspects of the former, but has much more serious editing capabilities and is more like a Photoshop than an iPhoto for iOS.

I also do use the normal camera regularly in combination with iPhoto and/or Snapseed for certain types of edits and sharing.

[image: Process app] [image: iPhoto app] [image: Snapseed] [image: Instagram]

Answer (score 2):

I'm still using an iPad (1st Generation) so I can't comment on picture-taking apps other than to say that with the consistent improvement to the standard **Camera**, particularly it's accessibility from the lockscreen, I find it's my goto camera on the iPhone 4S 99% of the time.

In terms of photo editing, the vast majority of my post production, including cropping, adjustments, filters and frames is done in one of two apps:

[**Snapseed**](http://www.snapseed.com/)

[image: image adjustment point in Snapseed]

By far my first choice for cropping, framing and post-production adjustments. The *Selective Adjust* feature makes this the *killer app* for photo editing. It allows you to set adjustment points on your image and apply the adjustments only to the defined areas.

[**Photogene for iPad**](http://www.mobile-pond.com/MobilePond/photogene/photogene-for-ipad/)

[image: image if Collage in Photogene]

Before *Snapseed* was released I did most of my photo adjustments in *Photogene*. These days I primarily use it for the *Collage* feature, but it remains a credible editing app in it's own right.

[**Photogene 2**](http://www.mobile-pond.com/MobilePond/photogene/photogene2-for-iphone/) is available for the iPhone and features a unique *scroll wheel* interface.

[image: image of filter screen in Photogene 2]

I have a handful of additional filter apps, but these two (three?) are the must have's.